# How to catch touch events for CG content in UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

I have a UIView subclass that draws a curved line within it's frame (using Core Graphics). As expected, when you touch somewhere within the frame the view fires a touch event. But I only want the touch event to fire when the actual line is touched. How do I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to setup some sort of collision detection. When you get a touch event in the frame, then call your "hit test" method. That method will simply check whether or not the touch point in the frame intersects with the curve.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the collision detection using CGPathContainsPoint.